# Ruby Syllable counter

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write some code that will do the following(using a class):

1. puts the haiku
2. count the lines and return true is there is 3 lines and false if there aren't 3 lines.
3. count the syllables in the haiku.

The first two I was able to achieve. However, my syllable counter isn't working, and I'm not sure why... Here is my code.

```
class SampleHaiku
  attr_accessor :paragraph
  def initialize(paragraph)
    @paragraph = paragraph
  end
  def paragraph
    @paragraph
  end
  def line_counter
    @paragraph.lines.count
    if @paragraph.lines.count == 3
      puts true
    else puts false
    end
  end
  def syllable_counter
    scount = []
    @paragraph.split(' ').each do |letter|
      if letter.to_s.downcase.include?("a")
        scount << letter
      elsif letter.to_s.downcase.include?("e")
      elsif letter.to_s.downcase.include?("i")
        scount << letter
      elsif letter.to_s.downcase.include?("o")
        scount << letter
      elsif letter.to_s.downcase.include?("u")
        scount << letter
      elsif letter.to_s.downcase.include?("y")
        scount << letter
      else scount << " "
      end
    end
    puts scount.to_s
    return scount.join('').split(' ').size
  end
end
haiku = SampleHaiku.new("green and speckled legs,
hop on logs and lily pads
splash in cool water")
puts haiku.paragraph
puts haiku.line_counter
puts haiku.syllable_counter
```

What gets puts out is this:

```
green and speckled legs,
hop on logs and lily pads
splash in cool water
true

["and", "hop", "on", "logs", "and", "lily", "pads", "splash", "in", "cool", 
"water"]
1
```

---Edit---

Things I considered for the syllable counter include the following:

1. count the vowels.
2. Diagraphs (two letters than spell one sound: "ai, ay, ee, ea, ie, ei, oo, oe, ey, ay, oy, au) count as one vowel(this is a general rule...I'm sure there may be a few exceptions.)
3. Words containing diphthongs count as one vowel. In my post I was only able to count the vowels which I know is only about 75% correct according to multiple sources.

Obviously I was unable to incorporate the 2nd and 3rd option into this, but the first option alone is correct about 75% of the time according to different sources I've seen on the web.

Also, when I change the haiku text to

"haikus are easy

sometimes they do not make sense

refrigerator"

The code suggested thus far gives the following...

```
def syllable_counter
  scount = []
@paragraph.split("").each do |letter|
  if letter.to_s.downcase.include?("a")
    scount << letter
  elsif letter.to_s.downcase.include?("e")
    scount << letter
  elsif letter.to_s.downcase.include?("i")
    scount << letter
  elsif letter.to_s.downcase.include?("o")
    scount << letter
  elsif letter.to_s.downcase.include?("u")
    scount << letter
  elsif letter.to_s.downcase.include?("y")
    scount << letter
  else scount << " "
  end
end
scount.to_s
return scount.join('').split(' ').size
end
```

puts

```
 haikus are easy
 sometimes they do not make sense
 refrigerator
 22
```

Versus

```
def syllable_counter
  @paragraph.scan(/[aiouy]+e*|e(?!d$|ly).|[td]|ed|le$/).size
end
```

puts

```
 haikus are easy
 sometimes they do not make sense
 refrigerator
 25
```

Comment: `paragraph.split(' ').each do |letter|` ... I don't think that `letter` is a letter, is it? `word`, perhaps?

Comment: Also, can you describe what the logic for calculating syllables in a word is supposed to be?

Comment: 1. count the syllables, 2. Diagraphs (two letters than spell one sound: "ai, ay, ee, ea, ie, ei, oo, oe, ey, ay, oy, au) count as one vowel(this is a general rule...I'm sure there may be a few exceptions.) 3. Words containing diphthongs count as one vowel. In my post I was only able to count the vowels which I know is only about 75% correct according to multiple sources.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is just checking for every word with a vowel (except e for some reason) and adding it to an array.

By doing `@paragraph.split(' ')` you are splitting into words and not letters. If you want to split into letters you must do `@paragraph.split("")`. But even then that would just count the number of vowels

You can check the first answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47322/how-to-count-the-syllables-in-a-word). It has a pretty good simple solution with regex.

You can just do 
`@paragraph.scan(/[aiouy]+e*|e(?!d$|ly).|[td]ed|le$/).size`

It's not perfect but it works most of the time.

If you want a perfect solution that would take a lot more thinking and knowledge of the english language.